# How to include external JS file in JSP file in Spring WebMVC framework?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

[image: My directory structure]I have tried below answer but it didn't work..

[How include an external JS file in a JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107788/how-include-an-external-js-file-in-a-jsp-page/53271602#53271602)

I have been searching on google but couldn't find anything useful...my JS file is at same level as that of WEB-INF..any help would be appreciated...

Below is the code that I'm using to include my JS file in JSP :-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.18.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/formValidation.js"></script>
```

below code is in web.xml :-

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Below code is in dispatcher-servlet.xml file :-

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.programcreek.helloworld.controller" />

    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `external` - In my thing an example of an external js file would be `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If this is not what you are asking, then show an example of your code and your directory structure (as text)

Comment: Give a screenshot of your project structure and post code where you are trying to link js file !

Comment: I have just now added ss of project structure and code that I have written to include my JS file.

Comment: @ScaryWombat...external file means I have written jquery code in a different file and I'm trying to reference that file in Jsp file...I have tried writing inline Jquery code in Jsp and its working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add `ResourceHandler` to resolve your static resources like `js/css` directory

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/js/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/js/")
        .setCachePeriod(3600)
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}
```

This method apply for java configuration class `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

The `xml` version should look like this

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
```

This will resolve any `.js` file under `/webapp/js/` directory, using something like below in `.jsp` file

```
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you please have a look at my directory structure once and my code and then let me know where to include this method?

Comment: You should create `resources` directory under `webapp` to store all static resources like `resources/js/` `resources/css/` then just simply set `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>` for all of them

Answer (score 0):

for help you can see this github link click [here](https://github.com/sehramadhvi88/springweb-mvc-example)
I hope it will help you
and this is the project structure

[image]